# How to display the Silhouette(AWS) in Rstudio?

Tags: r, k-means

I'd like to display the average silhouette (AWS) with a plot, it's for a homework , I have to get the AWS by using the function Kmeansrun, I see where is the parameter "aws" or "ch" in the parameter "criteron" in the function but I don't know how to get the awc values.

In my case, I'd like to display "aws" as the Ylab and the "number of groups" for the Xlab.

```
plot(1:10 ,Inertia, type =" b " ,xlab =" Number of groups" , ylab ="Inertia")
```

I'd like to get the same graphics but with "aws silhouette" instead of "Inertia".

This is how I got the inertia variable :

```
inertie . expl <- rep (0 , times =10)

for (k in 2:10) {clus <- kmeans(data, centers = k,nstart =5)
inertia[ k ] <- clus$betweenss / clus$totss  }
```

So do you know how to replace on the graphics the inertia by the silhouette by using the Kmeanruns function ?

Thank you very much :)

---

NEW EDIT : 
I finally found the solution, here it is :

```
silhouette <- rep (0 , times =10)

for (k in 2:10) {clus <- kmeansruns(data, krange = 2:10 , criterion = "asw", iter.max = 5, runs = 5, scaledata = FALSE, alpha = 0.001, critout = FALSE) 
silhouette[k] <- clus$crit[k] }
```

clus$crit[k] represents the criterion "asw" which is the average silhouette.
Then I can display it on a graphics :

```
plot(1:10 ,silhouette, type =" b " ,xlab =" Number of groups" , ylab ="Silhouette")
```

Comment: Please try and make a reproducible example with some sample data. Also, this is plain R and not RStudio so I'll edit the tags and title accordingly.

Comment: Yes you're right, this is true that my question was not very precise, I'll edit the title , but I found the solution anyway

Comment: You can answer your own question, this might help other people with the same problem (which is the whole point of Stack Overflow!)

Comment: you're right , it's done :)

Comment: You can put the answer in the answer box below the question! That way the question gets marked as answered and you can accept it as an answer.